# How to properly save netCDF file with stars

Tags: r, netcdf, stars

I'm trying to save properly formatted `stars` object to netCDF file with no success. Here is a reproducible example of what I'm doing.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stars)
# example data
ex <- tibble(longitude = 1:10, 
             latitude = 10:1, 
             date = seq(Sys.Date(), by = 'day', length.out=10), 
             var_1  = rnorm(10),
             var_2 = rnorm(10)*pi)

#converting to stars
ex_stars <- st_as_stars(ex, dims = c("longitude", "latitude", "date"))
st_crs(ex_stars) <- 4326

# perfectely as expected
stars object with 3 dimensions and 2 attributes
attribute(s):
            Min.    1st Qu.     Median       Mean   3rd Qu.     Max. NA's
var_1  -2.104233 -0.5401773 -0.3535653 -0.1928388 0.1472027 1.871511  990
var_2  -7.152977 -1.6175938  0.3478074 -0.2144949 1.7141039 4.550393  990
dimension(s):
          from to offset delta refsys point values x/y
longitude    1 10    0.5     1 WGS 84    NA   NULL [x]
latitude     1 10   10.5    -1 WGS 84    NA   NULL [y]
date         1 10  19251     1     NA    NA   NULL
```

But when I save it with `write_stars()` to netCDF file and reload it, I lost all the formating done... What should I pass to `write_stars()` to save correctely formated netCDF file?

```
write_stars(ex_stars, './tmp.nc', layer = c('var_1','var_2'))
read_stars('./tmp.nc')
Band1, Band2, Band3, Band4, Band5, Band6, Band7, Band8, Band9, Band10, 
stars object with 2 dimensions and 10 attributes
attribute(s):
                Min.      1st Qu.       Median         Mean      3rd Qu.         Max. NA's
Band1   -0.532665789 -0.532665789 -0.532665789 -0.532665789 -0.532665789 -0.532665789   99
Band2   -1.481356621 -1.481356621 -1.481356621 -1.481356621 -1.481356621 -1.481356621   99
Band3    1.367094874  1.367094874  1.367094874  1.367094874  1.367094874  1.367094874   99
Band4   -2.104233265 -2.104233265 -2.104233265 -2.104233265 -2.104233265 -2.104233265   99
Band5    0.193868801  0.193868801  0.193868801  0.193868801  0.193868801  0.193868801   99
Band6    0.007204485  0.007204485  0.007204485  0.007204485  0.007204485  0.007204485   99
Band7    1.871511102  1.871511102  1.871511102  1.871511102  1.871511102  1.871511102   99
Band8   -0.470182747 -0.470182747 -0.470182747 -0.470182747 -0.470182747 -0.470182747   99
Band9   -0.236947894 -0.236947894 -0.236947894 -0.236947894 -0.236947894 -0.236947894   99
Band10  -0.542681098 -0.542681098 -0.542681098 -0.542681098 -0.542681098 -0.542681098   99
dimension(s):
  from to offset delta refsys point values x/y
x    1 10    0.5     1 WGS 84    NA   NULL [x]
y    1 10   10.5    -1 WGS 84    NA   NULL [y]
```

Comment: ? ? ? Anyone ? ? ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just starting to explore solutions to a similar task, which is writing 3D ocean data (lat,lon,depth) directly into a netcdf file. My suspicion is that `write_stars()` is intended to write 2D objects (such as satellite data), which might be composed of several layers (Band1-10 in your example). However, it may not be well suited for multidimensional data.

With [version 0.6-0](https://r-spatial.github.io/stars/news/index.html) of the stars package, the function [write_mdim()](https://r-spatial.github.io/stars/reference/mdim.html) was added. According to the function description, it is intended to write multidimensional arrays.

Have you tried that function yet? If yes, I would be keen to read your code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: write_mdim(ex_stars, './tmp.nc', layer = c('var_1','var_2')) seems to do the trick with updated version of the package!

Comment: See here some examples using stars::read_mdim and stars::write_mdim : https://github.com/r-spatial/stars/issues/555